# Responsive CSS behaviour of a centered image

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the image container (`.colored-logo`) to span the width of the browser when I shrink it to mobile size. I have created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/robxs5n3/) so you can see the behaviour.

Apologies but I have placed all my CSS in here to make sure that whatever it is affecting it is included.

I am working on an email template and I am centering horizontally and vertically a logo into a boxed area with rounded corners.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="row invoice-top-header">
    <div class="column third colored-logo">
        <div class="logo">
            <span class="image-center"></span><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/ebd3rwub5/fresh_creations_logo.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column third">...</div>
    <div class="column third">...</div>
</div>
```

The `row` class adds a `15px` internal padding which I offset in the container (`colored-logo`) with a `-15px` margin left and right.

The CSS I apply is this:

```
.colored-logo {
    background: #989898;  
    height: 128px;
    margin: 0px -15px 10px -15px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-center {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why is the logo container (div with class `colored-logo`, dark grey background) not filling the browser horizontally once in mobile mode? It looks to be `30px` too short to cover the browser horizontally.Thanks!

Comment: which element is the logo container you are refering to?

Comment: Hi @Salketer, the container with the grey background color and the rounded corners. I want it to fill the screen horizontally (`colored-logo`). Thanks

Comment: " am working on an email template and I am centering horizontally and vertically a logo into a boxed area with rounded corners." - If this is an email template, it's unlikely to work with a vast majority of email clients.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, appreciate the vote of confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have padding both to your row class and your column.
Try this css if you want your changes to take effect only in mobile screens:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   .colored-logo, .row {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="invoice-top-header">
    <div class="column third colored-logo">
        <div class="logo">
            <span class="image-center"><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/ebd3rwub5/fresh_creations_logo.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    <div class="column third">
        <div class="biller-details"> 
            <span><strong>BILLER NAME PTY LTD</strong></span>
            <span>ADDRESS LINE 1</span>
            <span>ADDRESS LINE 2</span>
            <span class="desktop">TEL: 02 3333 4444</span>
            <span class="mobile">TEL: <a href="tel:02 3333 4444">02 3333 4444</a></span>
            <span>ABN: 12345678</span>
            <span>ACN: 09876543</span>
            <span><a href="mailto:sample@email.com" data-rel="external">sample@email.com</a></span>
            <span>my-website.com.au</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column third">
        <div class="customer-details"> 
            <span><strong>CUSTOMER NAME PTY LTD</strong></span>
            <span>ADDRESS LINE 1</span>
            <span>ADDRESS LINE 2</span>
            <span class="desktop">TEL: 02 5555 7777</span>
            <span class="mobile">TEL: <a href="tel:02 5555 7777">02 5555 7777</a></span>
            <span>ABN: 12345678</span>
            <span>ACN: 09876543</span>
            <span><a href="mailto:sample@email.com" data-rel="external">sample@email.com</a></span>
            <span>customer-website.com.au</span>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

1. Change your HTML into this one above
2. Remove margin css property from .colored-logo
3. If you are coding a newsletter you should really consider using tables and avoid css3 properties as many of the email clients still doesn`t support lot of things. Here you can find a list with email clint which does and doesn`t support media queries:

https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

Just tested and it works

Answer (score 0):

Disabling these values / properties seems to work

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* padding: 15px; */
    max-width: 1040px;
    width: 100%;
}

.colored-logo {
    background: #989898;  
    height: 128px;
    /* margin: 0px -15px 10px -15px; */
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Just adjust as required in your media queries.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/robxs5n3/4/)